# Retrieve Firebase realtime database in Json form using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have used Google Script to send data from Google sheet to firebase realtime database. Here I am trying to retrieve those data in json form. My real time databse looks like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
my service.ts

```
getRealData():Observable<any>{
      return  this.afs.collection('draft-memorial-default-rtdb')
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(item => {
      return item.map(value => {
        const ref = value.payload.doc.data();
        console.log(ref);
        return {
        ref
        };
       
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.auth.getRealData().subscribe(res=>console.log(res));
  }
```

I have done with other database but with realtime database how do we retrieve data if the data are stored from google sheet using google script?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Kfv.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
service.ts

```
getAll(): AngularFireList<any> {
      return this.tutorialsRef;
    }
```

component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getRealData();
  }
getRealData(): void {
  this.auth.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

It return the key value with they payload.